# DNS settings not saving or propagating

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

As of last week I am struggling connecting my squarespace site to my domain managed by godaddy. I Have various other sites for which this process went just well.

My new domain: pawfectstay.be is purchased via godaddy. We have a site created via squarespace.
First I tried connecting the squarespace site using the standard connector squarespace suggested. This did not work.
I figured I would add the dns records myself manually. I did this but after 72 hours it did not work.
I confirmed with dns checker and none of them recognized the domain.
I performed an nslookup from my laptop against nameservers specified by godaddy:
[NSlookup result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vujBw.png)
This actually gave back some results
I then perfomed the nslookup against 8.8.8.8 nxdomain result.
I read about misconfiguration of records cause propagation to not work so I figured I would start all over again and removed all dns records and add them one by one. However now I can't even add a normal A record:
[godaddy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drrjZ.png)

My questions now are:

1. Can I misconfigure something in order to block dns propagation?
2. Am I adding incorrect info now to get the goddady error?

EDIT:
I'll add current records:
Godaddy:[godaddy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2tT0.png)
Squarespace: [squarespace settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RSsf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too, so thank you for not redacting  and posting your actual domain name. One recommendation:  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots with console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you haven't completed the registration process.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this info! Where can I check this? Any chance you can point me in the right direction on how to complete this using godaddy? From the dashboard there is no more actions to be taken.

Comment: You should reach out to GoDaddy support if that's where you registered this domain.